# How to access and change source-code of sanity.studios?

Tags: database, cloud, sanity

I have joined a sanity.studio and I want to make changes to the modules and the structure of the contents. I have not developed the modules or the content, but I have full access to sanity.studio.

I want to change the structure of some of the schemas.
Is it possible to access the code, without having access to the original project folder the studio was developed i?

I do not want to change the schemas through API and Queries, I want the source-code the studio was created in.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.